# Digital Image Processing via Python

Tags: python, image-processing

I am starting a new project with a friend of mine, we want to design a system that would alert the driver if the car is diverting from its original path and its dangerous.
so in a nutshell we have to design a real-time algorithm that would take pictures from the camera and process them. All of this will be done in Python.
I was wondering if anyone has any advises for us or maybe point out some stuff that we have to consider

Cheers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for this libraries: dlib, PIL (pillow), opencv and scikit learn image. This libraries are image processing libraries for python.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your insight but I already knew about these, I was searching for more in depth advises about the problems and issues that I might encounter